# split a spreadsheet column into 3

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, break, cut

I have a spreadsheet that has 3 columns.  Business Name/Contact Name/Email address.  It's the Contact field where I need to change "Mr. John Doe" into "Mr" "John" "Doe".

I've learned as far as being able to find Mr or Mrs using:

cat merchent.csv | grep -E "Mr|Mrs"

The more I think on this process, I think it might be better to grab the whole field (with the file in CSV form) and then break up that field based on spaces.  I understand the concept, and that it will involve some use of 'cut' but I don't know it well enough(yet) to understand how to accomplish this.

Comment: Is the Contact field always formatted as 'Mr. FirstName LastName'? and are there spaces in the other fields? Please provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: OK, I've noticed that the field is mostly my initial quote but there are variations.  Mr./Mrs./Dr./Smt./(even a full name), then some have initials.  I could see breaking off the titles, and breaking off the last name and everything can be the 'first' name maybe.

Comment: @vishnurajv Exactly.  "Mr. John Doe" to "Mr" "John" "Doe" (thought I did that...already?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script.

```
cat merchent.csv | cut -d "," -f2 | while read; do
IFS='. ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$REPLY"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    # process "$i"
        echo -ne "$i "
done
echo " "
done
```

Here I'm guessing your data is like

```
business_name1,contact_name1(in the format Mr. John Doe),email_address1
business_name2,contact_name2(in the format Mr. John Doe),email_address2
```

Comment: That looks pretty cool but would I have to swap out the "IN" part to something like "cat merchent.csv | grep -E "<something here>""?  I need to feed a cvs file into this script.

Comment: use `cat merchent.csv | cut -d "," -f2`

Comment: What is the output though?  And I do believe I am doing this wrong....
'code'
IN="cat merchent.csv | cut -d "," -f2"

IFS='. ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    # process "$i"
        echo $i
done

Comment: Sadly I cannot, confidential client info in the file I am working with.

Comment: put your code in 'youcodehere'. Instead of typing ' from keyboard just copy paste from bottom instruction which appears while you type comment!

Comment: No need to put the actual data, just give an example of a row of your csv

Comment: "business name", "Mr Jon Doe", "email addresses1", "email address 2".  This is essentially what I noted in the initial question(with the exception of a possible second email address but was going to address that later...but since we are here now...)

Comment: 'IN="cat merchent.csv | cut -d "," -f2"

IFS='. ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    # process "$i"
        echo $i
done'

Comment: So, putting a single quote at the beginning and at the end didn't seem to help with formatting....